# Having trouble writing the correct GraphQL query in Node.JS for an AWS DataExchange Provider's API specification

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, graphql

I'm trying to write a GraphQL query to fetch data from an AWS DataExchange provider based on their company's API specification.

However, every query I've written so far isn't returning any data.

I've verified that all my AWS credentials and IAM keys are correct.

Could you please help me write the correct query based on the API specification given by the data provider.

My current request 'body' looks like below:

```js
Body: JSON.stringify({
  content: {
      "application/graphql": {
        "schema": {
          "$ref": "#/components/schemas/CatalogSearchRequest"
        },
        query: `query availablemetadatarecord(limit: 10 content: { catalogProperties: { vendor: { eq: "EYE" } } }) {
                 assignedId
        }
      }`
      }
  }
}),
```

The DataExchange provider's actual API specification looks like below.

```js
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "image-services",
    "description": "API Gateway for integration of Platform Services into AWS Data Exchange",
    "version": "2022-03-03T20:04:18Z"
  },
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": ""
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/psdm/graphql": {
      "post": {
        "requestBody": {
          "description": "GraphQL query for the Catalog in the form of:\n\n  `{\n    availablemetadatarecord(\n      QUERYPARAMS\n    ) { \n      FIELDLIST\n    } \n  }`\n",
          "content": {
            "application/graphql": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/CatalogSearchRequest"
              },
              "examples": {
                "Limit returned data": {
                  "description": "Limit the number of records in a response.\n\nIn your query, simply specify `limit: <int>` \n",
                  "value": "{\n  availablemetadatarecord(\n    limit: 10\n    content: { catalogProperties: { vendor: { eq: \"EYE\" } } }\n  ) {\n    assignedId\n  }\n}\n"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "required": true
        },
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "200 response",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/CatalogSearchResponse"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "sigv4": []
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "CatalogSearchRequest": {
        "title": "CatalogSearchRequest",
        "type": "object"
      },
      "CatalogSearchResponse": {
        "title": "Catalog Search Response",
        "required": [
          "data",
          "paginationInfo"
        ],
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "paginationInfo": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "recordsInPage": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "nextOffset": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            }
          },
          "data": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "availablemetadatarecord": {
                "type": "array",
                "description": "Records returned by query",
                "items": {
                  "type": "object"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "securitySchemes": {
      "sigv4": {
        "type": "apiKey",
        "name": "Authorization",
        "in": "header",
        "x-amazon-apigateway-authtype": "awsSigv4"
      }
    }
  }
}
```